# Using a IF statement in a DataFrame and getting an error: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

I have a data frame of stock prices and returns imported from yahoo finance as below.

| Date | price | return |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 | 54 | 0.05 |
| 2019-02-01 | 46 | -0.14 |
| 2019-03-01 | 48 | 0.04 |

where date is the index and the return is numeric.

I am trying to create a new column with will = equal 1 if the return on the following day is positive and equal -1 if the following return is negative.

I have used

```
if df['return'].shift(-1) > 0:
  df['Indicator'] = 1
else 
  df['Indicator'] = -1
```

However, I get the afformentioned error. I have tried using .all() but this makes all of the indicator column equal to 1. even when the return on the following day is negative

The desired output would be

| Date | price | return | indicator |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 | 54 | 0.05 | -1 |
| 2019-02-01 | 46 | -0.14 | 1 |
| 2019-03-01 | 48 | 0.04 | 1 |

The last 1 in the indicator column is assuming the return the following day, 2019-04-01 is positive.

Any advice?

Thank you

Comment: can you provide a multi-row example and the matching output for clarity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the numpy where function. Its more effective and simple:

```
import numpy as np
df['Indicator'] = np.where(df['return'].shift(-1)>0,1,-1 )
```

Comment: That's a good answer. I was going to `apply` onto the shifted Series because I find `np.where` extremely unintuitive but this works fine.

Comment: One should note, however that this will work only if you have a single row per day.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works great and is more concise than using an if else statement

Comment: Of course. In that case you first need make the dataframe unique by day.

Answer (score 1):

This would do I think:

```
df['Indicator'] = df['return'].shift(-1).apply(lambda x: 1 if x > 0 else -1)
```

Comment: it's too bad to use `apply` when you can use a vector operation ;)

Comment: Yeah @mozway. I didn't really think about the vector operation. Sorry!